Неизвестная интеграция
@bot.slash_command(name='removerole', description='Удалить роль у пользователя')
async def _remove_role(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
    if ctx.author.id == 743864658951274528:
        if member and role:
            if role:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                await ctx.respond(f'Роль «{role.name}» удалена для пользователя {member.mention}', ephemeral=True)
            else:
                await ctx.respond("Роль не найдена", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await ctx.respond("Роль или пользователь не найдены", ephemeral=True)
    else:
        await ctx.respond(f"{ctx.author.mention}, У вас нет прав на использование команды 'removerole'\nЗа покупкой к: "
                          f"<@743864658951274528>", ephemeral=True)

Ребята, помогите, пожалуйста. У меня есть команда чтобы забирать роли у пользователей, но недавно начала появляться ошибка при использовании этой команды. Когда я пытаюсь воспользоваться командой, то всё нормально работает, но при повторном её использовании бот пишет "Неизвестная интеграция". Он начинает работать после перезапуска Discord, но также всего один раз. В чём может быть проблема?
